# Recursively resolve placeholder

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a Regular Expression for parsing a string that contains placeholders in the form of ${anything}

This is easy enough, using something like this, I can extract $2:
 (\${(.*?)})

The difficulty comes when I want to nest placeholders, for example
if primary_region="americas", and americas1=unix-am-host1, then I would want
${${primary_region}1} to resolve to ${americas}1 as an intermediate and then finally to unix-am-host1

When I apply the regex above, $2 yields "${region" instead of just "region"
So I need a regex that when applied to ${${primary_region}1} will extract primary_region, and then when I apply it to ${americas1} it will extract americas1

Comment: You're looking for the inner braces. That's `\{([^{}]+)\}`. Otherwise, you need a recursive regex and an engine that supports it.

Comment: The best bet is to rematch from the beginning each time, inner to outer. Substitute inners each time `\$\{([^{}]+)\}` Replace your hashed value given $1 as the key.

Comment: @sin I ended you using your approach successfully. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it as correct

Comment: Ok, added it as a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your identifiers only contain word characters (judging by the examples they do), use `\w+` (that matches 1 or more `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` chars):

```
(\$\{(\w+)\})
      ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tG3cP7/1)

In case there can be any other characters but `{` and `}`, you can leverage a `[^{}]` negated character class:

```
(\$\{([^{}]+)\})
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tG3cP7/2)

Comment: Victor, you do not need recursion - unless you have provided wrong sample inputs and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

The best bet is to rematch from the beginning each time, inner to outer.

Substitute inners each time `\$\{([^{}]+)\}`
Replace your hashed value given `$1` as the key.